Dynamically execute the SQL statements that this SQL statement generates
I would like to dynamically execute the SQL statements that this SQL statement generates in Postgres Version 12:
select 'ALTER TABLE public.' || table_name || ' OWNER TO ' || '"new_owner";' 
from information_schema.tables 
where table_schema = 'public'

This will have to be done with approx 50 databases so not expecting to run this in pgadmin or psql - manually.  Ideally running this with psql with an input file within a for loop in bash.  I have a bash script that will connect to the 50 databases. I am not sure the best way to do this - functions, cursors, exec, combination of these, etc..
Thanks!

Using psql see example at \gexec section in link. Though I would strongly suggest adding Begin; before the SELECT. Then you can ROLLBACK in case of an oops.

nice suggestion!  I did not know that was possible.  However, I want to run this script in a file.  I have changed the description to be more accurate as to the requirements.  Let me know if I missed something and your solution can be run via a batch sql script file.

Create an anonymous function DO using Execute Dynamic commands.

@AdrianKlaver A DO statement to connect to 50 databases? With dblink? I think a shell script is a much cleaner and simpler solution.

@LaurenzAlbe. No I was thinking you could embed the function in the script.

@AdrianKlaver I see. Ok, why not.
